# Railside experience, good or bad?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ide

I saw a new Rails IDE called RailSide on AppStore earlier today (see http://itunes.apple.com/se/app/railside-rails-ide/id468367116?mt=12). Reading the description it looks interesting, but I wonder if anyone here has downloaded it and given it a thorough trial run.

Comment: I am intrigued by the idea of a Rails IDE, and am following this question appropriately.  Do respond, people.  Do.

Comment: I would never trade the extremely light, fast and efficient textmate for any IDE in the world.

Comment: And if this IDE was just as light, just as fast, and just as efficient?  It's possible, just curious if you're 100% attached to TextMate, or not.  I use it as well, and love it, but sometimes I do miss the bells and whistles of using Java in Eclipse, for example.